# SQL: Place the sum of data in table A (which is dependent on table B) into table C arranged according to table B. (sample data provided)

Tags: sql-server, group-by, sum

Basically, I'll have to group the people in Table 2 according to departments (known only through referring to table 1) and then sum each department according to type (known through Table 2). The results have to grouped by departments (known through table 1).

Can anyone help me execute such an action in SQL?

Sample data:

```
Table 1
DeptID | Dept
1      | Eng
2      | Mkt
3      | Mkt
4      | Eng

Table 2
Person | DeptID | Type | Amount
A      | 1      | p1   | 5
B      | 2      | p2   | 3
C      | 3      | p1   | 10
D      | 2      | p1   | 20
E      | 4      | p2   | 17
F      | 1      | p2   | 15
G      | 2      | p1   | 16

Table Results
Dept | Sum p1 |  Sum p2
Eng  | 5      | 32
Mkt  | 46     | 3
```

Comment: I think `Sum p1` for `Mkt` should be 46.

Comment: made the change. thanks for the notice!

Answer (score 0):

You could do this using conditional aggregation.

```
SELECT
    t1.Dept,
    [Sum p1] = SUM(CASE WHEN t2.Type = 'p1' THEN t2.Amount END),
    [Sum p2] = SUM(CASE WHEN t2.Type = 'p2' THEN t2.Amount END)
FROM Table2 t2
INNER JOIN Table1 t1
    ON t1.DeptID = t2.DeptID
GROUP BY 
    t1.Dept
```